# Is there any cross server sql request utility like linqpad?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linqpad, management-studio-express, cross-server

Is there any cross server sql request utility like linqpad?(at least pseudo cross server) or is there any way i can make cross server requests using management studio?

Comment: What have you already tried? You might want to Google for `linked servers` as this is probably what you are looking for if you want to execute queries across multiple SQL servers/instances.

Comment: actually i am looking for some utility that will get data from servers based on sql requests and merge it dynamically on my local machine

Comment: If I needed to do that (as I have many times), I would use SQL Server Management Studio and set up linked servers to allow me to access all of the necessary SQL instances from a single query - is there a reason why this would not work for you and you want to fetch the result set from each SQL server/instance separately and merge on your local machine?

Comment: i guess there is not:)
i've googled a bit about linked servers and figured out that its even more suitable for me than i could imagine, thank you!

Comment: No problem, I've posted an answer below with a little more detail and some example links for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, use SQL Server Management Studio and [Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188279.aspx).

Some specific resources here:

- [SQL Server Linked Server Example
  Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query)
- [Querying a linked sql
  server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495719/querying-a-linked-sql-server)

Googling for something like `SQL Linked Server Query Examples` should uncover everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer links to answers that cover 2 out of the myriad of options for doing cross server joins (including local possibilities as per the OPs comment)

- Linked Servers covered by other answer's link
- [OpenQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) covered by other answer's link
- [OpenDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160689/opendatasource-instead-of-linked-server)
- OpenRowSet
- [SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis)
- Using one of the `Open*` methods to make one server call another, which calls another.
- Linqpad can use any C#/Vb/F# code that can get data from multiple servers - not just a single drop down at the top, you don't even have to use that drop down for what you want. see [ADO.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ado.net)
- Composing an `Open*` query via code
- SSIS